# How to transform any JSON string to Map[Symbol, Any] using import play.api.libs.json?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.3

I cannot figure out if there is a way to transform a JSON fragment (as a String) in a `Map[Symbol,Any]` using `play.api.libs.json` library, where `Any` could be a `Int`, a `Double`, a `String` or a nested `Map[Symbol,Any]`.

Can anybody give me a hint to get this?

Comment: This is possible, but there are so many better ways to work with JSON in Play.

Comment: I know Travis, but the specific scenario I'm facing fits this approach very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JsObject.fieldSet` will give you a `Set[(String, JsValue)]` that you can transform into a `Map[Symbol, Any]`. You will have to pattern match on all possible subclasses of `JsValue` and transform each to the type you want.

For example, something like this:

```
 Json.parse(text) match {

    case js: JsObject => 
      js.fieldSet.map { 
        case (key, value) => Symbol(key) -> transform(value) 
      }.toMap

    case x => throw new RuntimeException(s"Expected object json but got $text")
 }

 def transform(jsValue): Any = jsValue match {
    case JsNumber(value) => value.toDouble
    ...ect...
 }
```